# Calling COM from an ASP.NET 2.0 application works a few times and then times out?

Tags: asp.net, com

I'm calling a COM object from an ASP.NET application.

Here is the code making the call:

```
 var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(config.ProgramId);
 var com = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
 var regionPropertyValue = ReflectionHelpers.GetProperty(com, "Region");
 var output = comType.InvokeMember("Execute",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, com, new object[] { data });
```

This call works for a few times and then eventually hang with the following error:

`Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {xxx} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8004e024.`

I'm not certain where to begin troubleshooting this. I've searched for the error code but am getting a mixed bag of results.

Does the .NET code look correct? Do I need to manually close or dispose of anything making the call?

Update:

Adding the following line to release the object stopped the call from timing out. Previous calls weren't releasing the object which was causing additional calls to hang.

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(com);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**This hotfix**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2523525) may be of interest to you. Seems like it is probably the same issue you're having.